# I have a DB named contacts and a table named person in it, What is wrong with the syntax in the SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLD1h.jpg

Here's the link to my code.

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Do you have a statement before this query? Perhaps you forgot to terminate it with a `;`?

Comment: No, I don't have any statements before the query.

Comment: You have a use statement that is not terminated before the select?

Comment: You have `USE contacts` before the query. It needs a semicolon before the query.

Comment: Oh yeah.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use` is a statement too - you need to terminate it with a `;` before the select:

```sql
USE contacts;
-- Here ----^

SELECT person_id
FROM   person;
```